# Scala Pattern Matching comparing a int to a list

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a recursive program for comparing a int to each value in a list. Problem is I keep getting a unreachable error, and I really don't know why. My code is

```
def isIn(x : Int, l : List[Int]) : Boolean = l match {
  case Nil => false
  case x => true
  case h :: t => isIn(x, t)
}
```

I really don't understand why this doesn't work. Or i guess, I am wondering how to compare x to the head using case.

Comment: I guess this might just be a simplified case or a learning exercise, but if you really just want to see if `x` is in the list, you can use `l.contains(x)` (or the slightly more type safe `l.exists(_ == x)`).

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that when you use a variable that starts with a lowercase character, the pattern matcher thinks that you are trying to assign to a new variable.  Of course, a pattern that is simply an assignable variable will match *anything*, so any subsequent `case` will be unreachable.

To solve this, you need to use a "stable identifier".  This can be done by putting the lowercased variable in backticks:

```
def isIn(x: Int, l: List[Int]): Boolean =
  l match {
    case Nil => false
    case `x` :: t => true
    case h :: t => isIn(x, t)
  }
```

or renaming the variable so that it starts with an uppercase character:

```
def isIn(X: Int, l: List[Int]): Boolean =
  l match {
    case Nil => false
    case X :: t => true
    case h :: t => isIn(X, t)
  }
```

Note that since each `case` must be a `List`, you need to have the `:: t` after `x` to show that `x` should be matching the head of the `List`.

Comment: Thank you so much this did it. I honestly smacked my head when I read this response. Through research I got the tick part but because i wasn't saying that x should be the head or x::t it kept giving me a error. I feel like such a dingbat thank you so much!

Comment: @David if this was helpful for you, maybe you would [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) the answer?